# cellTopLabel background color and cornerRadius

Tags: swift, object, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I want to make a rounded corner and background color for cellTopLabel, I have used this code:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = super.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath) as! JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell

    cell.cellTopLabel?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.cellTopLabel?.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    cell.cellTopLabel?.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell.cellTopLabel!.bounds.width/4, height: 20)

    return cell
}
```

But I obtain this result:

[image]

I don't want cellTopLabel to get entire screen width, but only the width needed, how can I fix this?

Comment: Some one has Any ideas?

Comment: were you able to make any progress on this.

Comment: No, i have modified the nib file of Cell

Answer (score 0):

Your code seemed to work for me so I would check that you have 
✅ autoresizes Subviews
checked in your properties inspector on the messages view.